# Simulation mode in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, simevents

I cannot find my "simulation mode" to adjust my pace to run a simulation. How can I add this to my toolbar? My interface is like pics below...It does not show me how to change the "simulation mode."

Not at my toolbar
[image: Not at my toolbar]
Not at my menu
[image: Not at my menu]

Comment: The relevant link is here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/performing-acceleration.html

Comment: The simulation mode parameter is called SimulationMode. Try setting it from command line using set_param(gcs,'SimulationMode','accelerator') and see if you get any errors. That might tell you why it is not shown.

Comment: It did not show anything on it. If I type "set_param(gcs,'SimulationMode','accelerator') " at my code, will it get accelerated?

Comment: I would try and see what happens. When running the model check the status bar and diagnostics window to see whether there are any messages related to accelerator mode.

Comment: It showed "The model 'untitled' uses Accelerator, or Rapid Accelerator mode. This license does not support these modes. The simulation will run in Normal mode." Then, I might need to buy a tool box for it?

Comment: "Compiler optimization level" is "off," however i can not turn it on...only can use the function "normal' and 'external

Comment: May be for home license the accelerator modes are not available. See for example, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/313059-accelerated-mode-availability

Comment: Yea! Thanks for your kind assistance, Navan.